# Codeception error "Class Yii not found" when trying to run

Tags: php, yii2, codeception

Currently working on a project for my apprenticeship. I have made some automated tests. I initialised codeception by running and built suite using

```
codecept bootstrap
codecept build
```

These 2 commands worked as expected but when I try to run the tests I get

```
FATAL ERROR. TESTS NOT FINISHED.
Class 'Yii' not found 
in /srv/http/blog/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Module/Yii2.php:242
```

Any got any ideas? I have looked at both Yii's and Codeceptions documentation but cannot find the solution.

*UPDATE*
new error message

```
FATAL ERROR. TESTS NOT FINISHED.
Class 'Yii' not found 
in /srv/http/blog/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/helpers/BaseUrl.php:129
```

Comment: Have you got Yii2 installed in this project?

Comment: Yes I am using the Yii2 framework, installed codeception and Yii2 through composer

Comment: Unfortunately, this area is poorly documented. Make sure to read: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-test-environment-setup.html and everything else about tests. For me it took quite some trial-and-error to get it working. Don't recognise your error though, but it's great to have tests finally working.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, the `_bootstrap.php` file wouldn't correctly load.
To fix this i've added the following to my `codeception.yml`:

#### Pre 3.0

```
settings:
    bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
    memory_limit: 1024M
    colors: true
```

#### Post 3.0

```
 bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
 settings:        
    memory_limit: 1024M
    colors: true
```

Don't really know what colors does, but it works for me.
Also here is my `_bootstrap.php` file for some insights on that as well.

use app\components\Helpers;

```
define('YII_ENV', 'test');

require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php';
require __DIR__ .'/../vendor/autoload.php';

$config = require(__DIR__ . '/../config/console.test.php');

//
$application = new yii\console\Application( $config );
```

The last two lines are ment to load your Yii class.
Hope this will work for u!

### Update for 3.0 and higher

From http://phptest.club/t/bootstrap-deprecations-in-3-0/2196

IF you are getting this message:

```
DEPRECATION: 'settings: bootstrap: _bootstrap.php' option is deprecated! Replace it with: 'bootstrap: _bootstrap.php' (not under settings section). See http://phptest.club/t/bootstrap-deprecations-in-3-0/2196 
DEPRECATION: Bootstrap file (_bootstrap.php) is defined in configuration but can't be loaded. Disable 'settings: bootstrap:' configuration to remove this message
```

Do the following:
[image: Do the following]

Comment: This is correct but putting bootstrap under settings is deprecated (and might be removed depending on when you are reading this). See http://phptest.club/t/bootstrap-deprecations-in-3-0/2196

Comment: Updated my comment, hope this helps for post 3.0 too now!

Answer (score -2):

The are some [issue](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/12885) in yii2 repo, pls check maybe it help you